# tkinter - All space characters are not getting displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a tkinter application for a Task list. I have used radiobuttons for each task as shown below:

```
for task in incompleteTasks:
    details = task[1]['name'] + '\n' + 'Date: ' + task[1]['date'] + \
              '   Time: ' + task[1]['time']
    Radiobutton(
        self.upper, text=details, justify=LEFT,
        variable=v, value=task[0]
        ).grid(padx=40, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

When `task[1]['date']` contains 10 spaces, not all of them are getting displayed.
Why is this happening?

list of tasks

[image]

Comment: How do you know that not all of them are displayed? Are you simply judging by their width? If so, are you sure your tkinter uses a monospace font?

Comment: And that's why you don't use spaces to align GUI elements. It just doesn't work without a monospace font.

Comment: I have added a link to the image that I am seeing. You can see that the space between Date and Time text fields is not the same.

Comment: what is a monospace font? How do I use it in my program?

Comment: a monospace font is a font where each char uses the same amount of space. that means, an 'i' has the same width as a 'm'. these fonts are preferred for code, e.g. `details = task[1]['name'] + '\n' + 'Date: ' + task[1]['date'] + '   Time: ' + task[1]['time']`. You can change the font of a Tkinter Radiobutton with `rbutton.configure(font=('Consolas', 12))` where rbutton is an instance of `Radiobutton`. ofc, Consolas is a monospace font ;)

Comment: also make sure that you assign the cunstructor call of `Radiobutton` to an instance variable that you can use / modify later